# How to permanently block KB4012218, KB4012219 and releated updates?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, windows-update

It appears Microsoft plans on antagonizing or punishing users who want to use Windows 7 and Windows 8 by [witholding security updates to the defective product](http://news.softpedia.com/news/kb4012218-kb4012219-released-to-block-windows-7-8-1-updates-on-new-processors-514158.shtml). It appears the updates that accomplishes it are KB4012218 and KB4012219.

I still use Windows 7 and with an occasional Windows 8. I have not acquired a taste for Windows 10. I don't agree to the change in the terms of service, and I don't agree to throw away my investments and purchases. I would like to permanently block the updates.

How do I permanently block KB4012218, KB4012219, and other related updates?

I've got a feeling a *Hide this update* in the Windows Update control panel is not going to work as expected. We know a bit about how Microsoft is going to handle things from the [Get Windows X](https://www.google.com/search?q=get+windows+x+malware) malware. That's why I am looking for a way to block "related updates", too.

Comment: My advice: Give up now. If you want to use modern hardware in a "supported" fashion, then you need to use an equally modern OS.  MS has no obligation to upgrade old OSs to support new HW.  If you need occasional Windows 7 and 8 access on your computer, run Windows 10 (or another OS that supports your hardware), and then fire up VMs.

Comment: Thanks @Techie. You seem to be conflating two issues. First is using "modern hardware"; and second is updates to "defective software". I already have my hardware with an OS, so I don't need updated hardware support. I do want the defective software updated. This question concerns itself with the updates, not the hardware.

Comment: No, you want the 'defective software' partially updated. Which isn't something the supplier of the updates supports. Take their advice.

Comment: Blocking those updates will not necessarily allow you to receive updates in spite of the "generational checks". Rather more likely is that any new updates *will* attempt to use the ability from those updates to check your hardware, fail because you don't have them and then not install the update at all. You could well be preventing yourself from receiving *any* updates instead of only updates that are relevant for your old hardware.

Comment: I suspect part of the issue people are having with the question is the *extremely emotive language*. And there's nothing stopping MS from blocking updates to systems without those patches. I'll leave it to you to decide if you want to edit it but terms like "defective product" are a bit strong - especially in this context, and considering the sources seem a bit clickbaity.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek - Sorry, I call it like I see it. The language is quite precise despite how the Microsoft Fan Boi's feel about it. For example, [defective product](https://www.google.com/search?q=legal+definition+of+defective+product) has specific meaning. I won't call it a *"feature"* to appease them.

Answer (score 9):

The Preview Updates are released next month as [Monthly Quality update](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/windowsitpro/2016/10/07/more-on-windows-7-and-windows-8-1-servicing-changes/)s, which includes Security Fixes + the Preview Roll from last month. And because all newer Monthly Quality updates include all older Monthly Quality update rollups you can't block them.

To avoid that you get the new Update Client that prevents you to scan for new updates on a AMD Ryzen or Intel Kaby Lake cpu, **only install the Security Only updatepacks each month** to have a system that is secure and up to date.

The April 2017 Security Only Update also seams to include the Update check.
What you now have do is to use [WSUSoffline](http://download.wsusoffline.net/) to get new updates to avoid using Windows Update.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an exact answer to this question, but people have created patches to circumvent the update mechanism.

Blog Post : https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/microsoft/user-made-patch-lets-owners-of-next-gen-cpus-install-updates-on-windows-7-andamp-8-1/

Actual patch : https://github.com/zeffy/kb4012218-19

> The only downside of these solutions is you have to apply a new patch
>   whenever wuaueng.dll [the patched DLL file] gets updated.